# Which of the following classes in java library do not implement a design pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Today, I came across this weird interview question. Which of the following classes in java library do not implement a design pattern?

1. Singleton
2. Observer
3. Iterator
4. Proxy

Does anyone have a clue? I doubt the correctness of the question, but wanted to know community opinion. If there is something I am not aware of, as none of the options make sense.

Comment: They are all associated with design patterns.  Are you sure you copied down all the options?  Maybe there was a fifth option?

Comment: Yes, this is the question. And, those are the answers.

Comment: There is no class named Singleton. Observer and Iterator are interfaces. I would pick the Proxy because it is a class and implements an HTTP Proxy, not the Design Pattern Proxy (code).

Comment: Yeah, it is kind of tricky question. It might be that there is no class called singleton, but definitely there are many classes implementing the pattern. Or, it could be proxy as you mentioned. But, not 100% sure yet.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind Even with `Proxy`, the question does not specify if it is `java.net.Proxy` or `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`. Which overall makes the question a silly one IMO.

Comment: This question seemed silly to me as well, so I wanted to know community opinion.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "following classes in Java library".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The official source for the Java standard library is the [standard Java API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/).

And one notable source for design patterns is the book [Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns).

To begin with, when you look at the options, the question (as quoted in your post) is badly formulated: *"Which of the following **classes** in java library"*...

*Only* the fourth option (`Proxy`) can refer to a class in the Java standard library. The other three are NOT classes in the Java library (they are either interfaces or they don't even exist as any type be it interface, class or enum). Also there are two `Proxy` classes in the Java library and this question doesn't specify which one. Either the question was misundertood (and incorrectly rephrased) or you may want to mention this inconsistency to whoever composed it.

So the correct option may either be the fourth option, or may be none of them depending on which `Proxy` we consider.

So let's take each option:

1. <strike>Singleton</strike>: There is no class (or even type) with such name in the JDK standard library. Also, Singleton is a design pattern. So not this option.
2. <strike>Observer</strike>: There is an interface (`java.util.Observer`) in the JDK, not a class. Also, Observer is a design pattern. So neither this one.
3. <strike>Iterator</strike>: same as Observer. It's an interface and refers to a design pattern.
4. Proxy: There are two classes in the JDK. `java.net.Proxy` represents a network proxy setting, hardly ever related to the proxy design pattern. If this is the proxy that's referred to, then the option is probably the correct one.

   If, on the other hand, we consider `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` which implements a [dynamic proxy class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html) that delegates method calls to other objects through an invocation handler, then this option would refer to a design pattern, making it not a correct option.

Comment: I wouldn't say the question was badly formulated, rather the question/problem was misinterpreted resulting in the OP misrepresenting it. It's probably not limited to *just* classes, and I highly doubt they'd put Singleton as an option if they were referring to the namespace of the Java API. @Imran You should definitely accept this answer for the bounty, as the other answer definitely isn't an answer

Answer (score 0):

Some claim the Singleton is an anti-pattern because it holds a global state. The others are definitely patterns.

Comment: True - it's basically equivalent to a global variable.

Comment: Still technically a pattern though. It's only an anti-pattern cause people abuse it, but can still be used properly.

Comment: (Aside: the term "anti-pattern" has the same problems as the phrase "best practice".  Someone is trying to paint a black-and-white picture that you should never do X.  It is very rare for there to be no exceptions.  The dogmatic approach is rarely justifiable **from a purely logical / objective perspective**.)

Answer (score 0):

Except Singleton, all the options are types (not **Classes** but types atleast) in Java. Considering some claims by others of "Singleton being anti-pattern", the first option seems to be correct answer to the question (if question was not messed up).